# Flask pytest fails when testing a route

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I don't know why my pytest fails when they shouldn't.

I have a REST API flask server, with the following folder structure:

```
.
├── api
│   ├── conf
│   ├── database
│   ├── error
│   ├── handlers
│   ├── models
│   ├── roles
│   ├── schemas
│   └── test.db
├── main.py
├── tests
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── test_routes.py
```

My tests are:

tests/conftest.py:

```py
import pytest

from main import app as flask_app

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    yield flask_app
    

@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()
```

tests/test_routes.py:

```py
def test_algorithms_get(app, client):
    res = client.get('/algorithms')
    assert res.status_code == 200
```

Now, I tried running `python3 -m pytest` in the `.` folder both with flask server running and not, but the test always fails and I get 404 status_code instead of 200. I know for sure that the route is perfectly working, but I can't get why the test fails.

This is the first time I use pytest (or any Unit Test framework) so I'm sure I'm missing something, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a total newb aswell. But have you tried using the full URL in `client.get`? Also seeing the actual code of the route might be usefull aswell.

Comment: @mzndr thanks for the response. I solved it. Indeed, it was a configuration error on how I was creating the Flask app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
It was a configuration error.

Indeed, I was making a mistake in the create_app() factory.

As I learned also, it is much better to define the create_app in the **init**.py file in the parent directory of your server (I was defining the function in main.py).

To be clear I moved the create_app factory definition here (*):

```
.
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py *
│   ├── conf
│   ├── database
│   ├── error
│   ├── handlers
│   ├── models
│   ├── roles
│   ├── schemas
│   └── test.db
├── main.py
├── tests
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── test_routes.py
```

New tests/conftest.py:

```py
import pytest

from api import create_app


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    flask_app = create_app({'TESTING': True})
    yield flask_app


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()

@pytest.fixture
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()
```

Finally, I call `python3 -m pytest` in the uppermost folder (`.`) to run the tests.

Now tests are working and I'm also able to create different configurations for testing and other use cases.